# from column to row array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array something like this:

```
0:"A"
1:"B"
2:"C"
3:"D"
```

I want to make to arrays.

One would look like this:

```
["A B C D"]
```

and second would look like this:

```
0: ["A B"]
1: ["C D"]
```

I tried with push and concat but without any result

```
var ar = array.push(temp[i].concat(temp[i + 1]));
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code? what is `temp`. It also looks like you are in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the results you are looking for.  However, I'm not certain of the context they are being used in so there may be a better way to do this if you show a bit more code.

```
let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];

// Use Array.join() to create a string using the
// array data.
let str = array.join(' ');
let array2 = [str];

console.log(array2) // ["A B C D"]

// Use Array.reduce() to create a new array based
// on the previous array's values.
let array3 = array.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    if (index % 2 !== 0) return acc;

    // EDIT: Added check to verify that the current
    // item is not the end of the array. 
    if (array[index + 1] === undefined) {
        acc.push([item]);
    } else {
        let newItem = array[index] + ' ' + array[index + 1];
        acc.push([newItem]);
    }

    return acc;
}, [])

console.log(array3) // [ ["A B"], ["C D"] ]
```

Reduce can be a little tricky at first.  Looking at this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) might help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["a","b","c","d"]; 
var ar = [];  
var i = 0;
ar.push(arr[i] + " " + arr[i + 1]);
```

I'm assuming you know the first array already.  So I'm just creating a new array and pushing the desired (var i) elements into the new one.  Then stick it into a loop, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to split your array into the chunk of `n` size. Then using `array#map`, you can iterate over the generated array and using `array#join` you can create the string of each array.

```js
let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
let combineArray = (arr, n) => {
  return arr.reduce((r,a,i) => {
    const index = Math.floor(i/n);
    r[index] = r[index] || [];
    r[index].push(a);
    return r;
  },[])
  .map(a => a.join(' '));
}
console.log(combineArray(array,2));
console.log(combineArray(array,4));
```